# kflorence jquery-wizard: branch validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, git, validation, branch

I'm using the kflorence jquery wizard: https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-wizard/ and I ran into an issue with validation when using branching.

I'd like to have the wizard show an error message instead of the defaulted "alert" when the selected option is blank. It currently works for regular steps, but when I get to a branched question, the validation does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            $("#example-3" ).wizard({
                transitions: {
                    q3: function( state, action ) {
                        var branch = state.step.find( "[name=q3]:selected" ).attr("class");
                        if (!branch ) {
                            ????
                        }
                        return branch;
                    },
                    q5: function( state, action ) {
                        var branch = state.step.find( "[name=q5]:selected" ).attr("class");
                        if ( !branch ) {
                            //alert( "Please select a value to continue." );
                        }
                        return branch;
                    },
                    q6: function( state, action ) {
                        var branch = state.step.find( "[name=q6]:selected" ).attr("class");
                        if ( !branch ) {
                            //alert( "Please select a value to continue." );
                        }
                        return branch;
                    },
                    q7: function( state, action ) {
                        var branch = state.step.find( "[name=q7]:selected" ).attr("class");
                        if ( !branch ) {
                            //alert( "Please select a value to continue." );
                        }
                        return branch;
                    },
                    q8: function( state, action ) {
                        var branch = state.step.find( "[name=q8]:selected" ).attr("class");
                        if ( !branch ) {
                            //alert( "Please select a value to continue." );
                        }
                        return branch;
                    }                       
                },
                beforeForward: function( event, state ) {
                    return !!$( this ).wizard( "form" ).valid();
                },
                afterSelect: function( event, state ) {
                    //$( "#progressbar2" ).progressbar( "value", state.percentComplete );
                    $( "#location2" ).text(Math.round(state.percentComplete) + "%");

                    if($('#unqualified').is(':visible')) {
                        $(".pad").hide();
                    } else {
                        $(".pad").show();   
                    };
                }
            }).validate({
                    rules :{
                        q1: {
                          required: true
                        },
                        q2: {
                          required: true
                        },
                        q3: {
                          required: true
                        },
                        q4: {
                          required: true
                        },
                        q5: {
                          required: true
                        },
                        q6: {
                          required: true
                        },
                        q7: {
                          required: true
                        },
                        q8: {
                          required: true
                        }
                      }
               });
        });
    </script>
```

I need the validation error to fire if the branch returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using:

```
if (!branch) {
    $("form").valid();
}
```